# Uniform random number generation from a set

Tags: matlab, random

I would like to find out if there is a function that can generate random numbers from a set of numbers in Matlab? For instance say I have the set [-1 1]. How can I generate numbers from that set? I have tried to use randi([-1,1]) but that obviously will generate the numbers -1,0 and 1 and I would like to generate numbers uniformly WITHOUT the 0 and only include -1 and 1. I apologise in advance if this seems like a trivial question but I can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Edit: I've found a simple solution for the above: (randi([0 1])*2) - 1. This only solves this problem and not a generation of numbers from a specified set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, is there a function that can generate integers uniformly from the set 1:2, or, in general, from the set 1:n, where n is the number of elements in your set? (Yes)

If the above answer was yes, then can those numbers be used as an index into the generated set? (Yes)

```
A = [-1 1];
n = numel(A);
A(ceil(rand*n))
```

Will it sample randomly and uniformly? (Yes)

Answer (score 1):

Generate a uniform random integer in the range 1 to N (where N is the size of the set).  Then use that to index into the set.

Comment: That is such an elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
>> S = sign(rand(1,10) - .5); S(S ~= 0)

ans =

     1    -1     1     1    -1     1    -1    -1     1    -1
```

This is obviously specialized to your specific example, but the same general concept can be applied.

EDIT: Here is a more general example:

```
>> Set = [1 10 100]

Set =

     1    10   100

>> Set(randi([1 3], 10, 1))

ans =

   100   100   100   100   100    10    10     1   100     1
```